# Expose result of method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, methods

I have this method :

```
// Parse a whole file
fs.readFile("klv-file.klv", (err, file) => {
    var KLVdata = KLV.parseKLVfile(file, options);
    var packets = KLVdata.packets;
    var nDropped = KLVdata.nDropped;
   
});
```

in a small Node app.

How to I get the variable packets outside this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. *Define* the variables outside the function, and set them inside. Like this:

```js
// Define variables
var packets = null;
var nDropped = null;

// Parse a whole file
fs.readFile("klv-file.klv", (err, file) => {
    var KLVdata = KLV.parseKLVfile(file, options);
    packets = KLVdata.packets;
    nDropped = KLVdata.nDropped;
   
});

function doSomething(){
    // you can now use the variables anywhere
}
```

Also: make sure to only use the variables if they have been defined.

```js
// Define variables
var packets = null;
var nDropped = null;

// Parse a whole file
fs.readFile("klv-file.klv", (err, file) => {
    var KLVdata = KLV.parseKLVfile(file, options);
    packets = KLVdata.packets;
    nDropped = KLVdata.nDropped;
    packetsReady(); // your callback function
});

function packetsReady(){
    // should only be called once the packets are ready
    processPackets(packets);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and the result of the "packets" variable is always null

Comment: @DimitriosFkiaras: See my newest update (callback function). Your `readFile` function is asynchronous, so it might not have completed by the time you wanted to use the variable. Can you send your code (on JSFiddle or something like that) so I can see exactly what's wrong?

Comment: No need. I think the callback function solved this thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass it to a function

```
let packets;
let nDropped;

function processKLV(KLVdata){
    packets = KLVdata.packets;
    nDropped = KLVdata.nDropped;
}

// Parse a whole file
fs.readFile("klv-file.klv", (err, file) => {
     processKLV(KLV.parseKLVfile(file, options));
});
```

Comment: I think there is a small typo. At the line before end it should read "parseKLV" instead of "processKLV" right? Nevertheless I still cannot access the contents of "packets" variable globally.

Comment: @DimitriosFkiaras, you are right, there was a typo. I updated my answer, however you will need to run your code /call your functions in the processKLV function because you need to wait for readFile to be done and my processKLV function is ran when readFile is done.